# How to make element sticky relative to an outer element when an intermediate element has overflow: hidden;?

Tags: html, css

Consider this HTML:

```
<div style="height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
  <div style="height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
    <p style="position: sticky">
      some sticky content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this snippet, the `<p`> is sticky relative to the inner div due to the `overflow: hidden`. Is it possible to make the `<p>` sticky relative to the outer div without:

- removing the `overflow: hidden`
- moving the `<p>` out of the inner div

Comment: Are you aware that position: sticky is an experimental API and shouldn't be used in production yet? (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky) It's not fully integrated and supported by all browsers. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility for browser compatibility and support.)

Comment: How about `position:fixed`?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError -  I wouldn't say that you "shouldn't use it in production". Most modern browsers ship with full support for it, and many usages of sticky are just an enhancement of UI, not a requirement. For that category I consider it more acceptable to have a non-sticky fallback for a (decreasing) part of my users than to bother all my users with a JS implementation.

Comment: @sideroxylon - I don't see how fixed would help me out here, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make the `<p>` sticky relative to the outer div
>   without:
>
> - removing the overflow: hidden
> - moving the `<p>` out of the inner div

Currently, this not possible - see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky):

> Note that sticky, by specification, will not work inside element with
>   overflow: hidden or auto. (ref: [Github issue on W3C CSSWG](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/865))

That said, in the Github issue above, there's a discussion about whether this limitation is actually according to spec or in fact a bug.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that part on MDN... Thanks!